# Does drush fire hook_exit()

Tags: drush

I am trying to write my own drush command. I have a hunch that something is not quite working right. I can't see documentation saying whether drush fires hook_exit()

Anyone know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by `grep -R exit *` in the drush folder, I think not. However, there is hook_drush_exit(), see docs/drush.api.php.